# Is there a way to print only the Spark SQL output? It is printing every other information about the environment while executing

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

If I am executing a spark-sql query like below

```
scala > sql("select name from emp limit 2") //emp is a hive table
```

it should display only the below line:

```
name
----
Tom
Dick
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by restricting Spark's logs to error level with:

`spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")`,

(given `spark` a `SparkSession`)